# Using Relay Kit to sponsor creation of a Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

Our goal is to create a Safe for all new users, based on their email. Is it possible to use Relay to sponsor the creation of the Safe?

I am following the Protocol Kit [instructions](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe) for deploying a Safe. But it abstracts away raw transactions, which Relay Kit [needs](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/relay-kit/gelato#prepare-the-transaction).

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this?